# creating a rest api and i need manual queries like select*from table where condition=false. where should i write that condition

Tags: android, spring, rest, api

> @Query(value="select * from student where active = true",nativeQuery= true)
>       Iterable findactivestudents(String firstName);

I should be able to use this query for `@getmapping` using API

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter in query like this

```
@Query(select p from Person p where p.forename = :forename and p.surname = :surname)
User findByForenameAndSurname(@Param("surname") String lastname,
     @Param("forename") String firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this Query to the corresponding repository file

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@EnableTransactionManagement
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {

@Query("SELECT * from Student where active = ?1",nativeQuery= true)
public Optional<List<Student>> findActiveStudents(boolean active);

}
```

Here Student is corresponding POJO file, and Integer is the datatype of it's primary key.

You can autowire this file in your controller file and call this public method.Code in the controller will look like --

```
@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

List<Student> studentList = studentRepository.findActiveStudents(true).get();
```